# Proving the area of a parallelogram in cases where coordinates are positive or negative.

Tags: number-theory

The Area Interpretation of the Determinant theorem says the following. Let (a,b) and (c,d) be nonzero vectors. Suppose that the angle swept out, counter-clockwise from (a,b) to (c,d), is less than 180 degrees. The determinant ad-bc equals the area of the parallelogram with sides given by the vectors (a,b) and (c,d).

I can prove the case when all coordinates are positive, but I am struggling to prove the case for positive or negative coordinates. I want to consider three cases, one for each quadrant. I recognize that symmetry will make Quad 1 and Quad 3 similar as it will with Quads 2 & 4.

Any help on how to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be the numerical value of the determinant which is the area.

Comment: Perhaps if you show your proof for positive coordinates, it might prompt someone to say how to extend it to negative coordinates. Use MathJax (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make the formulas legible.

Answer (score 1):

The area has nothing to do with where you put your origin.

Just shift your coordinate system to set the origin to the lower left point of the enclosing axis oriented rectangle around your four points.

Then you will always be in your first quadrant and can prove it the way you already know how to.